# Why does this function work even though the argument is missing?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand the following piece of code:

```
import Data.Char (ord)

encodeInteger :: String -> Integer
encodeInteger = read . concatMap ch
    where ch c = show (ord c)
```

But I don't see how this can work when `encodeInteger` is defined as a function that takes a string, but in the second line, the function is implemented without that string argument.

Also, `concatMap` (according to hoogle), takes a function and a list, but only the function `ch` is provided.

Why does this code still work? Is the argument somehow magically passed? Has it something to do with currying?

edit: And why doesn't it work to change it like this:

```
encodeInteger :: String -> Integer
encodeInteger a = read . concatMap ch a
    where ch c = show (ord c)
```

Comment: A function `a -> b -> c` in Haskell means a function `a -> (b -> c)`, i.e. if applied to an `a` it produces a `b -> c`. `f a b` is likewise just `(f a) b`. So since `concatMap` is (simplified) `(a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`, `concatMap ch` is a a function `[a] -> [b]`.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this somehow all makes sense. But shouldn't I able to do what I added under edit?

Comment: @user66875 you need to apply the entire composition to the argument. Right now, it is expecting `concatMap ch a` to be a function (the second argument to `.`). Use `read . concatMap ch $ a`

Comment: Why would you need to put arguments in that position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically defining a function

```
f = g
```

is the same as defining the function

```
f x = g x
```

In your specific case, you can use

```
encodeInteger a = (read . concatMap ch) a
```

to define your function. The parentheses are needed, otherwise it is parsed as

```
encodeInteger a = (read) . (concatMap ch a)
```

and `concatMap ch a` is not a function and can not be composed. At most you could write

```
encodeInteger a = read (concatMap ch a)
-- or
encodeInteger a = read $ concatMap ch a
```

About "why `concatMap ch` takes only one argument?". This is a partial application, which is very common in Haskell. If you have

```
f x y z = x+y+z
```

you can call `f` with fewer arguments, and obtain as the result a function of the remaining arguments. E.g., `f 1 2` is the function taking `z` and returning `1+2+z`.

Concretely, thanks to Currying, there's no such a thing as a function taking two or more arguments. Every function always takes only one argument. When you have a function like

```
foo :: Int -> Bool -> String
```

then `foo` takes one argument, an `Int`. It returns a function, which takes a `Bool` and finally returns a `String`. You can visualize this by writing

```
foo :: Int -> (Bool -> String)
```

Anyway, if you look up currying and partial application, you will find plenty of examples.

Comment: This is melting my brain, coming from other languages.

Answer (score 3):

```
encodeInteger :: String -> Integer
encodeInteger = read.concatMap (\char -> show $ ord char)
```

The `encodeInteger` on the left hand side (LHS) of "=" is a name; it refers to the function on the right hand side (RHS) of "=". Both have the function type: `String -> Integer`. Both take a list of characters and produces an integer. Haskell enables us to express such function equality without specifying formal arguments (a style known as [point-free](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree)).

Now, let's look at the RHS. The (.) operator composes two functions together. The composed function takes a string as its input from `concatMap` and produces an integer coming out of `read` as the output of the composed function.

`concatMap` itself takes 2 inputs, but we need to leave out the second one for the composed function, which requires a string as its input. We achieve this by partially applying `concatMap`, including only its first argument.