# Type synonyms unwrapping in functions?

Tags: haskell

Reading book by Simon Marlow "*[Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](https://web.archive.org/web20171204024223/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/web20171204024223/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/web20171204024223/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/web20171204024223/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/web20171204024223/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/web20171204024223/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/web20171204024223/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/web20171204024223/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/web20171204024223/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/web20171204024223/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/web20171204024223/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/web20171204024223/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/web/20180123022957/http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com:80/books/1230000000929/ch03.html)*" I encountered a thing I am not sure about why it works the way GHC sees it. Namely:

```
evalPair :: Strategy a -> Strategy b -> Strategy (a,b)
evalPair sa sb (a,b) = do
  a' <- sa a
  b' <- sb b
  return (a',b')
```

Has two input arguments (the way I see it `Strategy a` and `Strategy b`) on type level and one output - `Strategy (a,b)`.
But line under there are three arguments: `sa`, `sb` and `(a,b)`. It is confusing.

But since `Strategy` is type synonym:

```
type Strategy a = a -> Eval a
```

I thought that maybe if I unroll Strategies to (a -> Eval a) it will be clearer. So:

```
evalPair :: (a -> Eval a) -> (b -> Eval b) -> (a,b) -> Eval (a,b)
```

and (brackets added on the end)

```
evalPair :: (a -> Eval a) -> (b -> Eval b) -> ((a,b) -> Eval (a,b))
```

both compile.

Then I wrote it this way and thanks to Stack tooltips found that what is returned from function evalPair (went back to Strategy on purpose to make it more confusing) is not **`Strategy (a,b)`** but **`Eval (a,b)`**.

```
evalPair :: Strategy a -> Strategy b -> Strategy (a,b)
evalPair sa sb (a,b) = 
let res = do
          a' <- sa a
          b' <- sb b
          return (a', b')
in res
```

So clearly compiler unwrapped last argument from its type synonym, but only the last one - since we do not need to provide values for `Strategy a`
and `Strategy b`

**Here are my questions:**

1. Where can I get more information on this behaviour of the compiler? Why the function returns `Eval a` even though it says that it returns `Strategy a`
2. If unwrapping happens, then why don't I need (and can't in fact) provide values for `Strategy a` and `Strategy b` like so:

   ```
   evalPair :: Strategy a -> Strategy b -> Strategy (a,b)
   evalPair a sa a sb (a,b) = do
     a' <- sa a
     b' <- sb b
     return (a',b')
   ```

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of Haskell type annotation for functions. This is considered basic Haskell. See: [currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying).

Comment: In a nutshell, [all Haskell functions take just one argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43256681/2751851).

Comment: Personally, I also dislike that confusing mismatch between the type signature and the formal arguments. In such cases I prefer the style `evalPair sa sb = \ (a,b) -> ...` which is completely equivalent, but matches the signature more faithfully. (Even better, if we later on turn `Strategy` into a newtype, it's easier to add the wrappers.)

Comment: @chi It's nice to know I'm not alone in that :)

Comment: @chi: This is a good rule of thumb for clarity. It only makes a difference in a couple of rare cases—1. if the monomorphism restriction is enabled, using `f x = …` is a hint that you want a polymorphic function, while `f = \ x → …` will be a monomorphised value; and 2. GHC internally uncurries functions, and uses the number of parameters in the definition as a heuristic for inlining and when to allocate a closure for a partially applied function, which can affect performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the type synonym

```
type Strategy a = a -> Eval a
```

And the type

```
Strategy a -> Strategy b -> Strategy (a,b)
```

We can "desugar" the type by replacing each use of the synonym with its definition:

```
(a -> Eval a) -> (b -> Eval b) -> ((a,b) -> Eval (a,b))
```

Note that the parens are necessary here to clarify what's going on. The function `evalPair` still takes two arguments. Its two arguments are two *functions*. This may be clearer if I visually align the types with their corresponding arguments like so:

```
evalPair :: (a -> Eval a) -> (b -> Eval b) -> (a,b) -> Eval (a,b)
evalPair    sa               sb               (a,b)  = ...
```

Therefore the type of `sa` is `a -> Eval a`, and the type of `sb` is `b -> Eval b`.

Note that the Haskell Report states:

> Type synonyms are a convenient, but strictly syntactic, mechanism to make type signatures more readable. A synonym and its definition are completely interchangeable

Therefore, the compiler may freely "wrap" or "unwrap" type synonyms, as they are "completely interchangeable".

You can read about Type Synonyms in the Haskell Report, section 4.2.2:
https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-730004.2.2

Comment: Thank you, I missed the part about type synonym being completely interchangeable. Are we eligible to leave off brackets in Strategy (a,b) (in (a,b) -> Eval (a,b) form) strictly because it is a last argument to the function?

Comment: Haskell Report says:
"A function type has the form t1 -> t2, which is equivalent to the type (->) t1 t2. Function arrows associate to the right. For example, Int -> Int -> Float means Int -> (Int -> Float)."
https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-650004.1.2
So, whenever you see multiple arrows in a type, they "associate to the right", which means `a -> b -> c -> d` is equivalent to `a -> (b -> (c -> d))`. @AJFarmar's answer explains this in a little more depth.

Answer (score 4):

You are misunderstanding how Haskell functions work.

All Haskell functions have **only one argument**. If a function `f` takes a value of type `A`, and returns something of type `B`, we write `f :: A -> B`.

However, of course, we can write functions with multiple arguments, but in a clever way, called [currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying). If we want a function `g` that takes an `A` and a `B`, and produces a `C`, we actually write a function that takes an `A`, and then returns a function that takes a `B` and returns a `C`.

We write this as `g :: A -> (B -> C)`. However, since this is what we usually want to do with functions, the Haskell compiler will read the signature `g :: A -> B -> C` as the same thing.

This means that when we write `A -> B -> C -> ... -> Z`, we really mean `A -> (B -> (C -> (... -> Z...)))`.

However, if we write `g :: (A -> B) -> C`, **this is not the same thing! Brackets matter!** `g` is now a function that takes a function and produces a `C`.

Now, let's inspect this specific example:

```
 evalPair :: (a -> Eval a) -> (b -> Eval b) -> (a,b) -> Eval (a,b)
```

I read this as:

> The function `evalPair` takes the following:
>
> - Something of type `a -> Eval a`
> - Something of type `b -> Eval b`
> - Something of type `(a,b)`
>
> And produces something of type `Eval (a,b)`.

So the declaration would naturally look something like

```
evalPair first_arg second_arg third_arg = -- ...
```

Writing `evalPair a sa a sb (a,b) = -- ...` is nonsensical, since that takes 5 arguments, and thus `evalPair` would have a type of the form `a -> b -> c -> (d, e) -> f`, which is completely different to what we expect.

Comment: Thank you. Along with Dan Burton's abstract from Haskell Report now I understand what I missed.